# exiting the app when back button is pressed

Tags: android

I think this question has been asked several times,but this is a different scenario.I have 4 activities say act1,act2,act3,act4 and i had put intends such that act1->act2->act3->act4

act1-branch selection,
act2-year selection,
act3-subject selection,
act4-displays the selected subject
the user can press the back button from act4  it moves to act3 and can select different subject,similarly when he presses back button on act3,it moves to year selection activity i.e
act2.so i want  the 3 activities act1,act2,act3 to be alive so i did n't write the finish method.i had put home button in act4 that leads to act1.
when i press back button in act1 the app should close,but its forming a loop and all the prevoius activities opened are appearing instead.please,provide me the solution sorry if this question is too lengthy

Answer (score 2):

You should close all activities when coming back to activity 1 from activity 4, like the following code, using the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`:

```
Intent it = new Intent(Activity4.this, Activity1.class);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(it);
```

So in your activity 1 when you press the back button, it will finish the app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: this one only closes the act4,not the act3,act2 these are still appearing when i press the back button in act1

Answer (score 0):

In app1 add:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       startActivity(startMain);
 }
```

Comment: but this one is directing to home page,but if i want to get get the page where i open the app what should i modify in the above code

Comment: I think you want a normal intent, like @giacomoni has post.Intent it = new Intent(ActivityYouAre.this, ActivityYouWanToGo.class);
it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(it);

Comment: no i want to quit the app but the above code quits the app but home screen is appeared, i want to get the apps page where i open it after it quits

Comment: You want to close your APP and when you open again show where you left,  or you want to close and ACTIVITY and show the previous ACTIVITY?

Answer (score 0):

That's how it should work. Now in your stack you have act1 -> act2 -> act3 -> act4 -> act 1.
So when you press back button from act1 it opens only act4. What you have to do is, when starting act1 from act4 add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to your intent.What this flag does is, asks the android os to remove the previous activities from back stack.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the best way..but you can override the onBackPressed button of your **act1** and write

```
System.exit(0);
```

This will close the app instantly.
There may be better solution too